# Writing a unit test for ng-bootstrap modal (NgbModal) [Angular 6]

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ng-bootstrap

I am having some trouble writing unit tests for a confirmation modal I have in my app.  Here is the piece of code I would like to test:

```
  confirmModal(prompt = 'Are you sure?', title = 'Confirm'): Observable<boolean> {
    const modal = this.ngbModal.open(
      ConfirmModalComponent, { backdrop: 'static' });

    modal.componentInstance.prompt = prompt;
    modal.componentInstance.title = title;

    return from(modal.result).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        console.warn(error);
        return of(undefined);
      })
    );
  }
```

Any suggestions or examples?

Answer (score 14):

I've written the following test class based on your code snippet:

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgbModal, NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ConfirmModalComponent } from './confirm-modal.component';
import { MyComponent } from './test';

// Mock class for NgbModalRef
export class MockNgbModalRef {
    componentInstance = {
        prompt: undefined,
        title: undefined
    };
    result: Promise<any> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true));
}

describe('MyComponent tests', () => {

    let fixtureUnderTest: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
    let componentUnderTest: MyComponent;
    let ngbModal: NgbModal;
    let mockModalRef: MockNgbModalRef = new MockNgbModalRef();

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                MyComponent
            ],
            imports: [
                NgbModule.forRoot()
            ]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixtureUnderTest = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        componentUnderTest = fixtureUnderTest.componentInstance;
        ngbModal = TestBed.get(NgbModal);
    });

    it('should open modal', () => {
        spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);
        componentUnderTest.confirmModal();
        expect(ngbModal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ConfirmModalComponent, { backdrop: 'static' });
    });

    it('should set prompt and title to defaults', () => {
        spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);
        componentUnderTest.confirmModal();
        expect(mockModalRef.componentInstance.prompt).toBe('Are you sure?');
        expect(mockModalRef.componentInstance.title).toBe('Confirm');
    });

    it('should return the result of the modal', (done: DoneFn) => {
        spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);
        componentUnderTest.confirmModal().subscribe((result: boolean) => {
            expect(result).toBe(true);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should return undefined if there is an error', (done: DoneFn) => {
        spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);
        // Override the result returned from the modal so we can test what happens when the modal is dismissed
        mockModalRef.result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(false));
        componentUnderTest.confirmModal().subscribe((result: boolean) => {
            expect(result).toBeUndefined();
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

The tests are as follows:

1. **should open modal:** Tests the `ngbModal.open` method was called with the correct parameters.
2. **should set `prompt` and `title` to defaults:** Tests that `prompt` and `title` attributes are set correctly to their default values after the modal has opened. For this I had to add the following object to the `MockNgbModalRef` so that the values for prompt and title can be updated by the component itself.

```
componentInstance = {
    prompt: undefined,
    title: undefined
};
```

3. **should return the result of the modal:** Tests that the value of `modal.result` is returned from this method. With the method returning an Observable, I needed to subscribe to it and do the assert in within the subscribe. I've inject `DoneFn` so that `done()` gets called after the assertion. This means if the assertion never happens (e.g. there is an error in the component), `done()` never gets called and the test will fail.
4. **should return undefined if there is an error:** Similar to #3, however it checks that if the result of the modal was rejected (i.e. there was an error) then undefined is returned.

Comment: I tried this way, but i have problem with "returnValue(mockModalRef)", because it's return error - _"Argument of type 'MockNgbModalRef' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgbModalRef'. Type 'MockNgbModalRef' is missing the following properties from type 'NgbModalRef': _windowCmptRef, _contentRef, _resolve, _reject, and 4 more."_ How can I fix it?

Comment: @RafałGąsior for a quick fix, try changing `spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);` to `spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef as any);`

Comment: Hello @IanA  im following your test example but in the line  : spyOn(modalService, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);  i got "Argument of type 'MockNgbModalRef' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgbModalRef'.
"  do you have any idea please ?

Comment: @James does the fix in the second comment work? Changing `spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);` to `spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef as any);`